# loop over li and nested ul in each li tag and create list for data frame

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm having a html with some 24 div, in each div there is a h2 tag and ul tag. in the ul tag there are different number of li. In each li then there is h3 tag and a ul again, which again have a li tag with h4 tag enclosing and achor tag e.g.:

```html
<div class="medicine-category col-xs-6">
  <h2 class="tree-toggler nav-header">Anaesthesia</h2>
  <ul class="ulh nav nav-list tree">
    <li class="cat2-li">
      <h3 class="tree-toggler nav-header">Anaesthetics - General</h3>
      <ul class="ulh nav nav-list tree">
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/561/inhalational-agents">Inhalational
              Agents</a></h4>
        </li>
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/562/intravenous-inducing-agents">Intravenous
              Inducing Agents</a></h4>
        </li>
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/563/intravenous-diassociative-anaesthetics">Intravenous-
              Diassociative Anaesthetics</a></h4>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat2-li">
      <h3 class="tree-toggler nav-header">Anaesthetics - Local</h3>
      <ul class="ulh nav nav-list tree">
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/575/adjuncts">Adjuncts</a></h4>
        </li>
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/573/amide-type">Amide type</a></h4>
        </li>
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/574/ester-type">Ester type</a></h4>
        </li>
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/622/phenyl-methanol">Phenyl Methanol</a></h4>
        </li><span id="ezoic-pub-ad-placeholder-112" class="ezoic-adpicker-ad"></span><span
          class="ezoic-ad medrectangle-3 medrectangle-3112 adtester-container adtester-container-112"
          data-ez-name="medicineindia_org-medrectangle-3"><span id="div-gpt-ad-medicineindia_org-medrectangle-3-0"
            ezaw="200" ezah="200"
            style="position:relative;z-index:0;display:inline-block;padding:0;min-height:200px;min-width:200px;"
            class="ezoic-ad">
            <script data-ezscrex="false" data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript"
              style="display:none;">if (typeof __ez_fad_position != 'undefined') { __ez_fad_position('div-gpt-ad-medicineindia_org-medrectangle-3-0') };</script>
          </span></span>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat2-li">
      <h3 class="tree-toggler nav-header">General Anaesthetics-Adjuncts</h3>
      <ul class="ulh nav nav-list tree">
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/9/analgesics">Analgesics</a></h4>
        </li>
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/569/anticholinesterases-inhibitors">Anticholinesterases
              Inhibitors</a></h4>
        </li>
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/32/antiemetics">Antiemetics</a></h4>
        </li>
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/572/bronchodialator">Bronchodialator</a></h4>
        </li>
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/568/depolarising-neuromuscular-blockers">Depolarising
              Neuromuscular Blockers</a></h4>
        </li>
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/571/h2-blockers">H2 Blockers</a></h4>
        </li>
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/570/muscarinic-receptor-antagonists">Muscarinic
              Receptor Antagonists</a></h4>
        </li>
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/566/neuroleptics">Neuroleptics</a></h4>
        </li>
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/567/non-depolarising-muscle-relaxants">Non
              Depolarising Muscle Relaxants</a></h4>
        </li>
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/18/respiratory-stimulants">Respiratory
              Stimulants</a></h4>
        </li>
        <li class="cat3-li">
          <h4 class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a
              href="//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/565/sedative-antianxiety-drugs">Sedative-Antianxiety
              Drugs</a></h4>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
<div>
<h2>h2 title</h2>
<ul>
 <li>
  <h3>h3 title</h3>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <h4>
     <a href="https:test1.com">h4 title</a>
    </h4>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul
</div
```

I'm trying to create a list and subsequent dataframe:

```
content_list = []
for ele in content:
    row = []
    h2 = ele.find('h2').text
    row.append(h2)
    content_list.append(row)
    ul = ele.find_next('ul')
    for li in ul.find_all('li'):
        if li.find('h3'):
            h3 = li.find('h3').text
            row.append(h3)
            content_list.append(row)
            if li.find('ul'):
                li_ul = li.find('ul')
                for lii in li_ul.find_all('li'):
                    if lii.find('h4'):
                        h4 = lii.find('h4').text
                        a = lii.find('a').get("href")
                        row.extend((h4, a))
                        content_list.append(row)
```

the result list i'm getting is:

```
[['Anaesthesia',
  'Anaesthetics - General',
  'Inhalational Agents',
  '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/561/inhalational-agents',
  'Intravenous Inducing Agents',
  '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/562/intravenous-inducing-agents',
  'Intravenous- Diassociative Anaesthetics',
  '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/563/intravenous-diassociative-anaesthetics',
  'Anaesthetics - Local',
  'Adjuncts',
  '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/575/adjuncts',
  'Amide type',
  '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/573/amide-type',
  'Ester type',
  '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/574/ester-type',
  'Phenyl Methanol',
  '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/622/phenyl-methanol',
  'General Anaesthetics-Adjuncts',
  'Analgesics',
  '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/9/analgesics',
  'Anticholinesterases Inhibitors',
  '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/569/anticholinesterases-inhibitors',
  'Antiemetics',
  '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/32/antiemetics',
  'Bronchodialator',...
```

How can I get a list like this:

```
 [
    ['Anaeshtesia', 'Anaesthetics - General', 'Inhalation Agents', '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/561/inhalational-agents'],
    ['Anaeshtesia', 'Anaesthetics - General', 'Intravenous Inducing Agents','//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/562/intravenous-inducing-agents'],
    ['Anaeshtesia', 'Anaesthetics - General', 'Intravenous- Diassociative Anaesthetics','//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/563/intravenous-diassociative-anaesthetics'],
    ['Anaeshtesia', 'Anaesthetics - Local', 'Adjuncts', '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/575/adjuncts'],
    ['Anaeshtesia', 'Anaesthetics - Local', 'Amide type', '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/573/amide-type']
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep appending to your `content_list` multiple times within your loop. you should only be appending on the last step once you have completed a `"row"`. Also something seems off in the logic. Without having the full html, it's hard to debug at the moment.

Try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.medicineindia.org/medicine-categories'
html = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find_all('li', {'class':'cat2-li'})

content_list = []
for ele in content:
    title = ele.find_previous('h2').text
    sub_title = ele.find('h3').text
    
    ul = ele.find('ul')
    for li in ul.find_all('li'):
        row = [title, sub_title]
        h4 = li.find('h4').text
        row.append(h4)
        
        href = li.find('h4').find('a', href=True)['href']
        row.append(href)
        
        content_list.append(row)
```

**Output:**

```
[
    ['Anaesthesia', 'Anaesthetics - General', 'Inhalational Agents', '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/561/inhalational-agents'], 
    ['Anaesthesia', 'Anaesthetics - General', 'Intravenous Inducing Agents', '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/562/intravenous-inducing-agents'], 
    ['Anaesthesia', 'Anaesthetics - General', 'Intravenous- Diassociative Anaesthetics', '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/563/intravenous-diassociative-anaesthetics'], 
    ['Anaesthesia', 'Anaesthetics - Local', 'Adjuncts', '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/575/adjuncts'], 
    ['Anaesthesia', 'Anaesthetics - Local', 'Amide type', '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/573/amide-type'], 
    ['Anaesthesia', 'Anaesthetics - Local', 'Ester type', '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/574/ester-type'], 
    ['Anaesthesia', 'Anaesthetics - Local', 'Phenyl Methanol', '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/622/phenyl-methanol'], 
    ['Anaesthesia', 'General Anaesthetics-Adjuncts', 'Analgesics', '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/9/analgesics'], 
    ['Anaesthesia', 'General Anaesthetics-Adjuncts', 'Anticholinesterases Inhibitors', '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/569/anticholinesterases-inhibitors'], 
    ['Anaesthesia', 'General Anaesthetics-Adjuncts', 'Antiemetics', '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/32/antiemetics'], 
    ['Anaesthesia', 'General Anaesthetics-Adjuncts', 'Bronchodialator', '//www.medicineindia.org/generic-medicine-by-category/572/bronchodialator'],
    ...
```

Comment: Its giving me the same result. https://www.medicineindia.org/medicine-categories, this is the source of my html

Comment: ah ok. I see. We need to move where the row is initialized.

Comment: @MohammedSafeeUddin, see the edit above